# How to preform geom_text_repel if you don't have y value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this kind of code:

```
 feature1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, color = str_wrap(name, 20))) + 
  geom_line(stat = "density", bw = 0.5, size = 1) +
  labs(x = "score", color = "Features")
```

And I want to add `geom_text_repel`. But it doesn't work because it requires x, y and label, while I don't have y in my aes(), y is counted using density function. What can I do with that?

Answer (score 1):

one approach:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

data.frame(x = rnorm(1000)) |>
    ggplot(aes(x = x)) +
    geom_line(stat = 'density', bw = .5) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label = round(after_stat(density), 2)),
                    stat = 'density', bw = .5,
                    n = 10 ## ten density labels
                    )
```

[image: label density at various points]

Comment: Thanks! But how can I make it such that there will be only one label on the right side (near two)?

Comment: and why there is no parameter n in help? o_O

Comment: Found the `n`-argument in `?geom_density`. You might have to move some calculations outside ggplot, using e.g. `ecdf` or `stepfun` for density estimates, and feed these results via the `data` argument into the one or other ggplot layer.